# Refresh a table after upload file with Alpine js

Tags: laravel, alpine.js, filepond

I'm developing a Laravel application and I've got a view where displayed file data in a table.
When I upload a file via Filepond input type file, I want the view to refresh using Alpine js to display the new uploaded file.
How can i do?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXZEM.png) is the view

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0V9o.png) is the main .js file where I use Alpine and Filepond

Comment: Hi FilePond dev here, I don't have any experience with Alpine (yet), but you can use the `onprocessfile` callback to detect when a file was uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

From Rik's answer I would assume the simplest way to integrate is to store the file's information into Alpine.js state post upload by FilePond.

```js
Alpine.store('fileInfo', {
  loading: false,
  file: null,
  setFileInfo(file) {
    this.file = file;
  }
});

// Alpine initialisation code

// onreadystatechanged wrapper etc

FilePond.create(element, {
  // other config
  process: {
    // other config
    onprocessfile: (error, file) => {
      Alpine.store('fileInfo').setFileInfo(file);
    }
  }
})
```

In your template or in your Alpine component you can do `$store.fileInfo.file` or `this.$store.fileInfo.file` respectively.

Here are the docs for `Alpine.store`: https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store